# Removing child entity without setting parent_id to NULL in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If we have two sqlalchemy models, where a Child model has deletion flag:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    children = relationship('Child', primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id==Child.parent_id, not_(Child.is)deleted))')


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForegnKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    parent = relationship(Parent)
```

When I remove `child` from `parent` with:

```py
parent.children.remove(child)
```

SQLAlchemy sets `child.parent_id` to NULL. Is there any way to remove child from parent's `children` list, but keep `parent_id`? Right now I do:

```py
child.is_deleted = True
session.flush()
session.refresh(parent)
```

which removes `child` from `children` list, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, not as long as your relationship is dependent on Child.parent_id.